# Problema al seleccionar multiples items en RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Buen día, tengo una implementación la cual selecciona múltiples items en el `RecyclerView` he tomado la respuesta de la siguiente pregunta para guiarme:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551984/14856176

Pero al parecer no se adapta a mis necesidades ya que enfrento el siguiente problema al seleccionar el item funciona correctamente al igual que al des-seleccionarlo el problema radica cuando selecciono un item y luego selecciono un segundo item justo en este momento no lo selecciona si no que debo darle una segunda vez al item para que lo seleccione y lo mismo pasa si selecciono el primero (lo selecciona) luego selecciono el segundo (no lo selecciona) y luego selecciona el tercero (si lo selecciona) es como si cada vez que selecciono un item al seleccionar el segundo no se cumpla la condición, sin embargo en el `logcat` si se muestra que ha sido seleccionado pero el item no aparece con el color seleccionado, bueno sin mas mostrare lo que tengo por ahora:

En primer lugar creo un booleano en el modelo:

```
boolean isSelect = false;
```

Y su metodo getter y setter

```
public boolean isSelect() {
    return isSelect;
}

public void setSelect(boolean select) {
    isSelect = select;
}
```

Luego en el adaptador dentro del `onBindViewHolder` creo una instancia del modelo

```
Complementos user = listaUsuarios.get(position);
```

Bajo esa instancia creo el color por defecto que tendrán los items (o algo así?)

```
holder.itemView.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(user.isSelect() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE));
```

Por ultimo dentro del `onClickListener` cambio el color cada vez que se selecciona (Validando si es true o false ya que isSelect de entrada es false):

```
user.setSelect(!user.isSelect());
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(user.isSelect() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE));
```

Sin embargo en el **logCat** si me aparece que el item fue presionado:

Presione el primer item (Se marco)

```
ViewPostIme pointer 0
ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

Presione el segundo item (No se marco pero si apareció en el logcat)

```
ViewPostIme pointer 0
ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

Presione el tercer item (Se si marco)

```
ViewPostIme pointer 0
ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

Y asi sucesivamente...

Y creo que eso seria todo como ven ni si quiera es algo complejo sin embargo no parece funcionarme de la misma manera, no se si es porque utilizo `CardView`? o he cambiado `setBackGroudColor` por `setBackGroundTintList` espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: tu código esta correcto pero solo guarda en  onClick() el valor de la propiedad directamente en el objeto del listado, agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que realizas es correcto, creas una propiedad y su respectivo getter y setter para definir cuando el elemento esta seleccionado o no.

```
boolean isSelect = false;

public boolean isSelect() {
    return isSelect;
}

public void setSelect(boolean select) {
    isSelect = select;
}
```

**El problema es que estas modificando el objeto pero no estas modificando el objeto en el List que es de donde se obtiene la propiedad para cambiarlos de color y mostrarlo seleccionado.**

Lo que debes realizar es modificar la propiedad directamente en el objeto de List ya sea  `listaUsuarios.get(i).setSelect(false)` o `listaUsuarios.get(i).setSelect(true)`:

```
List<Usuario> listaUsuarios;
    
 ...
 ...
    
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsuarioViewHolder usuarioViewHolder, int i) {

       final Usuario user = listaUsuarios.get(i);

        usuarioViewHolder.tvNombre.setText(listaUsuarios.get(i).getNombreExamen());
        usuarioViewHolder.tvPrecio.setText(listaUsuarios.get(i).getPrecioExamen());

        //A partir de aquí comienza la lógica para pintar cada cardView del recyclerView

        usuarioViewHolder.view.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(user.isSelect() ? Color.GRAY : Color.rgb(0, 151, 167)));
        ...
        usuarioViewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
            ...
            //*Guarda valor al dar clic en listado.
            if(listaUsuarios.get(i).isSelect() == true){
                 listaUsuarios.get(i).setSelect(false);
            }else{
                 listaUsuarios.get(i).setSelect(true);
            }        
            ...
            ...
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hola, Elena gracias por tu respuesta, en en caso de esta linea if(listaUsuarios.get(i).getSelect() == true), "getSelect" de donde lo obtendria? veo que lo obtienes del modelo pero no me lo reconoce ya que no he creado ningun getter en el modelo llamado "getSelect", gracias

Comment: Perdón es  if(listaUsuarios.get(i).isSelect() == true){ , tu código es correcto solo realiza este cambio que comento en la respuesta.

Comment: @AdielMoran tu idea para realizar esto es buena pero el problema solo es que estas modificando el objeto pero no estas modificando el objeto en el List que es de donde se obtiene la propiedad para cambiarlos de color y mostrarlo seleccionado.

Comment: Hola Elena comentarte que gracias a lo que comentas y añadiendo tu respuesta ya he logrado el resultado y ya me funciona a la perfección, te lo agradezco mucho!

Comment: Excelenta @AdielMoran, solo tenías un pequeño detalle, que bueno que funcionó!

Answer (score 1):

hay que tener en cuenta algo importante con esta metodología de holder de los `RecyclerViews` y es que utilizas una sola instancia para crear todos los items por lo que debes crear variables que te administre las diferencias entre cada item

en tu caso utilizas la clase `modelo`

por lo que si creas una instancia de esta clase por cada ítem esto debería funcionarte sin problemas, debería ser así:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Model> mModelList;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getListData());
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private List<Model> getListData() {
      mModelList = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
          mModelList.add(new Model("TextView " + i));
      }
     return mModelList;
    }

    public class Model {
    
        private String text;
        private boolean isSelected = false;
    
        public Model(String text) {
          this.text = text;
        }
    
        public String getText() {
          return text;
        }
    
        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
          isSelected = selected;
        }
    
    
        public boolean isSelected() {
          return isSelected;
        }
    }

    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    
        private List<Model> mModelList;
    
        public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Model> modelList) {
          mModelList = modelList;
        }
    
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
           View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
           return new MyViewHolder(view);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final Model model = mModelList.get(position);
            holder.textView.setText(model.getText());
            holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(model.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);
            holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    model.setSelected(!model.isSelected());
                    holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(model.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);
                }
            });
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mModelList == null ? 0 : mModelList.size();
        }
    
        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
            private View view;
            private TextView textView;
    
            private MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                view = itemView;
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

lo único que cambie de la respuesta que mostraste fue en que el onbindviewholder al que le cambio el color es al `textView` y no al `view`

así queda

[image: resultado]

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta y por tomarte el tiempo amigo, comentarte que a pesar de que he tratado de buscar la diferencia del código que me muestras con mi código no encuentro ninguna por favor me ayudaría bastante haciéndome ver donde cambia mi código con el que tu me muestras, gracias!

Comment: Comentarte que ya he realizado el cambio pero me sigue dando el mismo problema!

Comment: la única diferencia que veo es que utilizas una variable llamada user

Comment: deberías verificar si esta asignada con el modelo de la posición así deberia estar en onbindviewholder final `Model user = mModelList.get(position)`

Comment: segundo es muy importante esto `mModelList.add(new Model("TextView " + i))`

Comment: osea debes crear una instancia de modelo por cada ítem muy importante

Comment: Dejame asimilar la respuesta de Elenasys y luego comento como me fue con tu respuesta!

Comment: Hola, gracias a tu respuesta y la de Elenasys adaptándolas ya he logrado el resultado, te lo agradezco mucho!